# Prove of f^m=f^k

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Prove that for any f :Jn → Jn, there exists a positive integer m such that *f^m = f^k*
for
some positive integer k < m.

I'm totally stuck with the prove. Any inputs will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You have asked 9 questions and accepted zero answers. Moreover you show zero effort when asking questions, never typesetting math and never showing your work. I wonder then why one should help you.

Comment: Are Jn's finite?  (what are Jns)  If the Jn's are finite then this is trivially easy.  Just think about it a *tiny* bit.